# How to convert a string value to Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I receive a string in the format given below (with double quotes around it):

```
 "'{ "param" : "value"}'"
```

How can I convert this string into json object so that I could use it as

```
alert(obj.param)
```

Thank you

---

### Edit

As I mentioned in above the string has double quotes around it. Here is an example of how I get this string

CSHTML

```
@{
    var prop = "{ \"param\" : \"value\"}";
    <a data-type="@prop"></a>
}
```

and in JS I have this

```
var obj = anchor.data('type');
```

I want to be able to use obj.param, how do I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object

Comment: Please check here for more details:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) it parses a string as a JSON

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

Comment: @csharp_beginner replace `var obj = anchor.data('type');` by `var obj = JSON.parse(prop);`